# How to call cmake and make commands from a Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake

I have the following Python script.

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

def Build(cmake_args):
    cmake cmake_args  # How to call cmake here by passing in the arguments?
    make install  # How to call make install here from within Python?

os.mkdir('build')
os.chdir('build')

# Call method Build by passing in all correct arguments
Build('-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./install" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$PWD/../packages" ../SourceCodeFolder')
```

**Question:**
How do I call `cmake` by passing in all Cmake arguments that my `CMakeLists.txt` understands? And then how do I call `make install`?

**Environment:**
I am running Python 3.9.0 on macOS Catalina.

**PS:**
I have ensured that `mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./install" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$PWD/../packages" ../SourceCodeFolder` succeeds when run from the bash shell. *So, its only a question of how to call cmake and make from my Python script*.

**Edit:**
I want to run my script on Macos as well as Windows. This is the reason for running cmake and make from a Python script.

Comment: I believe you could explain what you are trying to do with cmake, I think you're trying to automate some compiling tasks by using python, and I think that using python is not the most efficient solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subprocess.run(["command", "-arg"])`

(from https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)